# $\mathrm{erf}(\eta) = 0.95$, what is a method to get $\eta$ value from the expression?

Tags: calculus, error-function

I have an error function $\mathrm{erf}(\eta) = 0.95$.

How can I calculate the value of $\eta$ from this expression?

I know that $\eta \approx 1.4$. And I can get the value of $0.95$ by using Excel's ERF.PRECISE(1.4) function. However, I would like to know the reverse process, i.e. how to find $\eta$ from having only $\mathrm{erf}(\eta) = 0.95$.

Comment: In the complex field there are many values of $\eta$ for a given value of the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find a method for the calculation of the inverse of the $erf(\eta)$
http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1968-22-101/S0025-5718-1968-0223070-2/S0025-5718-1968-0223070-2.pdf
For small values of $x$, you can write:
$$erf(x)^{-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_nx^{2n-1}$$
and you obtaine the following expression for $C_n$:
$$1+\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty(2m-1)C_mx^{2m-2}\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1}C_nx^{2n}-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\right)$$
if you put $x=erf(y)$ and so $y'=\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\exp(y^2)$,
$y''=2yy'y'$
and then
$$-\dfrac{1}{y'}=2\int_0^xy(t)dt-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt\pi}$$

Comment: Generally, link only answers are looked a little down upon. Links can die. However, I liked the link, maybe you could add the most important parts to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: =NORM.INV(prob,mean,sd)

For your case =NORM.INV(0.95,0,1)